# Appcelerator titanium build takes about 2 minutes

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Hi titanium team / Experts,

I'm using Titanium and I look for a way to make my app build faster so it won't take so long to test it every time. Even when I run it twice without adding anything, it takes about 2 minutes to build and 15 more seconds to install on my device.

I think the key is in "Forcing rebuild: JavaScript files need to be re-encrypted". Is there a way to avoid this rebuilding?

The development is being done under mac machine

Comment: The most of people answering here are not Appcelerator's employee, and the answer only as a form of volunteering/personal branding. For this kind of message probably Titanium Jira would be a better place.
https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I cant sign in to the jira system with my appcelerator mail and password

Comment: You have to create an account. I only meant that here nobody gets your money so if you want to receive an answer is probably better if you change a bit your question.

Comment: Hi Mauro, can you please help me with the rebuild issue. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you included how you are building your app. Studio? CLI? Straight to device? Emulator?

Answer (score 5):

Rebuilding application can, depending on your mac specs, take 2 minutes indeed. A much faster way of developing is using LiveView or TiShadow (if you're using open source tools). Both methods don't need re-compiling but will only recompile files that need recompiling.

Be aware both methods do not fully clean the app when restarted/rebuilding, things like event listeners, collections and models can cause issues. So every now and then an actual restart is required, and sometimes bugs can appear that only appear during liveview development. But mostly, especially for UI improvements these methods greatly increase development speed.

Comment: The main issue is the full rebuilding every time, is there a way to prevent it?     ..." I think the key is in "Forcing rebuild: JavaScript files need to be re-encrypted""

Comment: have you read my answer? I explain in there it can in fact take that long, and I explain how to work around it

Comment: @RenePot Yes it may take that long, but Boaz Lautman is asking how to prevent a rebuild when no changes have been made in the first place.

Comment: @RenePot Although that would prevent a rebuild, it doesn't explain why Boaz is getting the `Forcing rebuild` message when no changes been made. Surely if you press build when no changes are made, titanium should understand to use the existing build made previously and not force a rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to speed up your builds. Some of which is described here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29002843

However I also discuss some other methods.

### TiShadow

Consider using [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/). It can simultaneously live deploy and test across multiple real devices using any OS for development. I've used it for some time, and it's AMAZING! Don't understand how anyone uses Titanium without it

### Use ccache

The Android NDK r7, required by V8 and Titanium Mobile 1.8+, can use ccache, a tool for reusing cached C/C++ compilations. We get huge improvements in build time with it.

1. Install HomeBrew if you don't have it installed already
2. Install ccache with the following command: brew install ccache
3. Set an environment variable NDK_CCACHE to point to it. Installed with HomeBrew, the command would be: export NDK_CCACHE=/usr/local/bin/ccache

### Parallelize Compiling

The NDK can also parallelize while compiling, which can speed up the process.

1. Determine how many cores your machine has. You can use this command on Mac OSX: `system_profiler | grep -i "Number Of Cores"`
2. Multiply the above number by 2. So if the above command returned Number of Cores: 2, then your value should be 4.
3. Set an environment variable NUM_CPUS equal to the above value. In this case: `export NUM_CPUS=4`

### Don't Build the Docs on Every Compile

Skip building the JSCA files (the files used by Titanium Studio's code assist feature). You don't need them if you're just making a build for yourself for testing. To skip, run scons like this:

```
scons build_jsca=0
```

### Live View

Live view reduces the need to recompile as is decribed here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/LiveView

### Speed Up Emulator

Although this doesn't really speed up your build time, speeding up your emulator helps speed up run-time a lot. Some methods are described here: https://gist.github.com/adam-lynch/7247983

[GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is also a much faster emulator I have been told. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Good answer. Though Android Emulator from Android studio is faster than Genymotion. I would recommend that ;)

Comment: @RenePot I have always been told Genymotion is a lot faster, but I haven't really used it myself yet. Been recommended it a lot though.